# Can I insert a sqlalchemy result to a different cloned db?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I want somthing like this

```
    result = original_session.query(table)
    clone_session.add(result)
    clone_session.commit()
```

or any other solution so that i can take data from one table and insert it to its clone.

Answer (score 0):

You need the create 2 differents sessions for 2 differents db.

for example:

```
session_maker_one = sessionmaker(bind=engine_one)
session_one = session_maker_one()

session_maker_two = sessionmaker(bind=engine_two)
session_two = session_maker_one()
```

*of course two different engines

Then, when querying from the first db:

```
table_one_data = session_one.query(Table).first()
session_two.add(table_one_data)
session_two.commit()
```

Comment: yaa created that say session_one is oiginal_session  and session_two is clone_session in my example but can i directly use the result got from session_one in session_two for same database object

Comment: have you tried the above code it produces  *** UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'sqlalchemy.util._collections.NamedTuple' is not mapped

Comment: so you should check what the result you get, might be .first()[0]

Comment: result.__dict__ then removing _labels key helped with a regular table.insert()